# run twice when dynamic import module in python

Tags: python, import

I need to build a Menu using curses in python.
When user select choice, it run a function within a sub-module.

I have first a json file which contains the menu structure:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Action A",
    "function": "main.foo.actionA"
  },
    "name": "Action B",
    "function": "main.bar.actionB"
  }
]
```

I have a main script which call the the menu.load method below:

```
import curses
import json

class menu:
  def __init__(self):
    self.curses = curses
    self.screen = self.curses.initscr()
    self.menuItems = json.loads(<my json menu file>)

  def load(self):
     x = 0
    while x != ord('q'):
      self.screen.addstr(2, 2, "Make your choice")
      i=1
      for item in self.menuItems:
        self.screen.addstr(i, 4, item['name'])
        i+=1

      self.screen.refresh()
      x = self.screen.getch()

    if x == <my id item id matching the menu>:
      //for example
      self.run("main.bar.actionB")

   def run(self, action):
     function = action.split('.')
     // Clear the screen, remove curse stuff so I can see intercative things in the terminal

     _temp = __import__("lib.functions.%s" % function[0], globals(), locals(), [function[1]], -1)
     mod = getattr(_temp, function[1])()
     result = getattr(mod, function[2])()

     // Once run is done, get back to menu
     self.load()
```

This is working fine (I didn't paste all the code because there is submenu).
BUT, when user run first action first time, it works.
Then, once user is back to the menu, he can run again the same action, and then, I can see the action running twice.
If I run the same action third times, it runs three times...etc etc

I first though the importer was importing menu each times and then some kind of reference was found ... so I've tried to add control with:

```
try:
  <run the function>
except AtributeError:
  //function is not loaded, load it
```

But it didn't work..

Comment: Please show the rest of the code, what you have here wouldn't cause anything to be run multiple times.

Comment: edit to add more code, I think I've put the most important part of code

Comment: In fact, the functions was not run multiple times, that was the logger which was writting logs as many times as I init new logger.handler :)